# how to tackle this large set of data that has to be filtered

Tags: angular, store, ngrx

Hi i would like to ask a conceptual question.

Let's say i have 100000 blogs that have a tag and date parameters. On each request to API I pull n (20) blogs to the store and in a component i
I show latest 10.

I have 3 components:
Component 1: shows all the data no meter the tag and sorts them desc by date.
Component 2: shows filtered data for a tag = "angular" and sorts them desc.
Component 3: shows data for tag="vue" with date sort.

Problem: How to pull data from api and how to store it? 
If Component 2 is first to load data from API then there are 50 records in store all with tag "angular"

then user opens Component 1: which calls the effects and their are 50 records the store so there is no call to API.

Question how would you define the store and API calls so that Component 1 always shows the correct ( mixed )  data but does not call the API unnecessarily?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. `Component 1` will always be independent since contains the all the blogs and it must implement the pagination to avoid heavy traffic and dom element.
2. If you still wants to use existing `Component` which are tag based then you must have tag `map` which keeps the tag name and its collection

   ```
   {
     'angular' : [.. blogs ..],
     'vue' : [..blogs..]
   }
   ```

Iterate over above map and create new array and this final `array` can be used in `Component 1`.

Comment: sorry but this does not help me. I think i am left with the same problem ? I am doing it opposite way i have { blogs: [] } and for component 2,3 i filter the result.                                                                          
In your case i would be doing the same but combining the results from angular and vue. Problem i have that there are more tags so i want to keep them in same store except that component 1 must show blogs in correct order ( there can be other tagged blogs between ) i hope i explained it ok